# Css media query orientation:landscape in android web view not working properly

Tags: android, html, css, media-queries, android-webview

I have an android web view in which I put this Html.

```
<style><!--
img{
width: 100%;
}
.piccolo{
font-size:3vw;
color:#000000;
}
.container{
margin-left:2%;
}
.paragraph{
padding-top:5px;
float:left;
}
@media (min-width: 800px) , (orientation:landscape){
.piccolo{
font-size:2vw;
color:#000000;
}
.container{
margin-left:2%;
display:flex;
padding:5px;
}
img{
width:50vw;
float:left;
}
.paragraph{
padding-left:10px;
}
}
--></style>
<br />
<h2 style="font-size: 6vw; text-align: center;">SOFTRAY ENGINEERING</h2>
<div class="container" style="padding: 10px;">
<div><img src="https://www.softray.it/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/experience.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<div class="paragraph" style="float: right;"><span style="font-size: 4vw; color: #000000;"><span style="font-size: 4vw; color: #000000;">Il cambiamento &egrave; buono,</span> <br /> <span style="font-size: 4vw; color: #000000;">la trasformazione &egrave; anche meglio</span></span>
<p><span class="piccolo">SoftRay&nbsp;aiuta le aziende a ridefinire il modo con cui operare e servire i clienti. Offriamo tecnologie di business complete o integrabili&nbsp;per ottenere risultati tangibili per il cliente.</span></p>
<p><span class="piccolo">Vediamo digitale sia dalla prospettiva aziendale, sia da quella del consumatore.</span></p>
<p><span class="piccolo">Cliente Digitale, &egrave; dove stiamo cambiando come coinvolgere e interagire con i clienti finali, professionisti, pazienti e studenti.</span></p>
<p><span class="piccolo">Azienda Digitale, &egrave; dove stiamo aiutando le imprese a ripensare radicalmente le loro&nbsp;strategie e attivare nuovi modelli operativi e processi di business. Creare piattaforme di prodotto, migliorare analisi e capacit&agrave; di collaborazione hanno l&rsquo;obbiettivo di aumentare la produttivit&agrave;.</span></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Before I put `(orientation:landscape)` the query applied only to a tablet and not to my phone.
The `(orientation:landscape)` applies the query in my phone even while it's in portrait. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by putting `(min-device-aspect-ratio: 1/1) and (orientation: landscape)` instead of only `(orientation:landscape)`

Answer (score 0):

I think browser is not able to read your media query due to comma (,). Try to use this

```
@media (min-width: 800px) and (orientation:landscape) { }
```

Comment: isn't that a logic AND? if my device is in landscape but it doesn't reach 800px I don't this this will work. Anyway I solved it and the comma works.